# ARKit : Handle tap to show / hide a node

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am new to ARKit , and i am trying an example to create a SCNBox on tap location. What i am trying to do is on initial touch i create a box and on the second tap on the created box it should be removed from the scene. I am doing the hit test. but it keeps on adding the box. I know this is a simple task, but i am unable to do it

```
    @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("hande  tapp")
    guard let _ = sceneView.session.currentFrame
        else { return }

    guard let scnView = sceneView else { return }
    let touchLocation = sender.location(in: scnView)
    let hitTestResult = scnView.hitTest(touchLocation, types: [ .featurePoint])

    guard let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView else {return}
    print("point   \(pointOfView.name)")

    if hitTestResult.count > 0 {

        print("Hit")

        if let _ = pointOfView as? ARBox {

            print("Box Available")
        }

        else {

            print("Adding box")

            let transform = hitTestResult.first?.worldTransform.columns.3
            let xPosition = transform?.x
            let yPosition = transform?.y
            let zPosition = transform?.z
            let position = SCNVector3(xPosition!,yPosition!,zPosition!)

            basketCount = basketCount + 1
            let newBasket = ARBox(position: position)
            newBasket.name = "basket\(basketCount)"
            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(newBasket)
            boxNodes.append(newBasket)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**pointOfView** of a sceneView, is the rootnode of your scene, which is one used to render your whole scene. For generic cases, it usually is an empty node with lights/ camera. I don't think you should cast it as ARBox/ or any type of SCNNode(s) for that matter.

What you probably can try is the logic below (*hitResults are the results of your hitTest*):

```
if hitResults.count > 0 {
    if let node = hitResults.first?.node as SCNNode? (or ARBox) {
    // node.removeFromParentNode()
    // or make the node opaque if you don't want to remove
else {
    // add node.
```